# How do I make a User Profile form using OnetoOneField extending the User Model?

Tags: django

I would like to make a form that extends the User Model using OnetoOneField. It would basically be a form in which a user can add/update their information after they have registered.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)  # max_length = required
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=120)
    paypal_id = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ["username", "name", "email", "paypal_id", "bio"]
```

views.py

```
def userprofile_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)

        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.save()

            return redirect('account')
    else:
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    context = {'profile_form': profile_form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/account_create.html', context)
```

template.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}    
<form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ profile_form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I keep getting this error when I hit Save:

> (1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")

Is there any fix for this?

Comment: the field user is required for the model, but dont appear in the form. for this view the user is currenly authenticathed?

Comment: if user is authenticated, you can save profile with adding user field to your form or overwriting your code to : profile.save(user=request.user)

Answer (score 1):

You can create both user and profile models at once using a generic create view.

Forms:

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ["username", "name", "email", "paypal_id", "bio", "user"]

class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

View:

```
class CreateUserProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
model = Profile
form_class = UserProfileForm
user_form_class = UserForm
template_name = 'accounts/account_create.html'
success_message = "Profile created successfully"
success_url = reverse_lazy('profile-list')

def get(self, request):
    profile_form = self.form_class()
    user_form = self.user_form_class()
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'profile_form': profile_form, 'user_form': user_form})

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    profile_form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    user_form = self.user_form_class(request.POST)
    if all([profile_form.is_valid(), user_form.is_valid()]):
        user = user_form.save()
        profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = user
        profile.save()
        messages.success(request, self.success_message)
    else:
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'profile_form': profile_form, 'user_form': user_form})

    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
```

Comment: I found the problem and it works! Is there a way to create the Profile form without having the UserCreationForm on the same page? I want the Profile form to be able to get information from the user and create/update the Profile Table (and be linked to the User Table). There are fields such as email and name that overlap in the two Tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to overwrite save() method of Profile to create/update User on-the-fly while saving Profile.

I.e.:

```
class Profile(models.Model):

...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if not self.user.pk:
            self.user = User.objects.create_user(self.user.username, password=self.user.password)

        self.user.save()  # mandatory as create_user is not recognized as save operation
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and produces the error saying 
`RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at <url>
Profile has no user.
`
I intend to create a Profile form that only contains the email from the UserCreationForm Model. The rest fields are created/updated when the user hits save on the Profile form.

Comment: @MusaKhan, notice the arguments on `create_user` in my example. In your case, I think it should be `self.username` as your Profile model contains username. Though, I don't see the password field in the form

Comment: I apologize if I wasn't being clear. What I'm intending to do is, create an independent form (Profile form) that has the fields ("username", "name", "email", "paypal_id", "bio") and link this information to the user in the User table. The only thing common between the forms would be the email address and username.

Comment: @MusaKhan The main idea is that during the save of Profile (which is linked one-to-one to User) handle also saving of User.
In case it does not exist - create. Update the necessary fields (e.g. add before save `self.user.email = self.email`) and save both dependant user and the profile.